# Can't bind Ctrl-J in bash

Tags: bash, bind

I'd like to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to a command in BASH, specifically I'd like to do this:

```
bind '"\C-j":"clear; ls *\n"'
```

But it seems that because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> is the linefeed key, the escape sequence \n calls whatever <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> is bound to, so the result of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> is:

```
clear; ls *clear; ls *clear; ls *clear; ls *clear; ls * ...
```

Is there any way to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and retain the meaning of \n? Or is there an alternative to `\n`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, it's about shell configuration. Could be a candidate for http://SuperUser.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the `\n` to make the command execute immediately. In that case, yes, there is an alternative:

```
bind '"\C-j":"clear; ls *\r"'
```

... should do what you want. (The `\r` is carriage return, usually bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, which usually has the same effect.)

Answer (score 0):

`bind -p | grep "not bound" | grep -v "self-insert" | cat >> keycodes-notbound.txt`
`bind -p | grep -v "not bound" | grep -v "self-insert" | cat >> keycodes-used.txt` will give you a list of all keybindings.

That way you can see in the .txt file which keycodes are not bound/in use.

Could be, that you have to unbind the bound function (accept-line, IIRC) that is bound to C-j.

Somthing along in this [How can I unbind and remap C-w in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980575/how-can-i-unbind-and-remap-c-w-in-bash) could help you, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shell command to be executed, you have to use the `-x` option:

```
bind -x '"\C-j":"clear; ls *"'
```

From `help bind`:

```
bind: bind [-lpsvPSVX] [-m keymap] [-f filename] [-q name] [-u name] [-r keyseq]
 [-x keyseq:shell-command] [keyseq:readline-function or readline-command]
Set Readline key bindings and variables.
```

Compare the parts:

```
[-x keyseq:shell-command]
```

and

```
[keyseq:readline-function or readline-command]
```

Without `-x`, `bind` controls readline functions or macros, and with `-x` `bind` will bind to a shell command to be executed.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use your window manager keyboard key bindings ?