# How can I unbind and remap C-w in Bash?

Tags: bash, readline

I'd like to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> to `kill-region` in Bash 4.2. This key is bound to `unix-word-rubout` (delete word backward) by default. According to the manual, remapping should be possible with the `bind` command which has the options

> -u function
>       Unbind all keys bound to the named function.
>
> -r keyseq
>       Remove any current binding for keyseq.

I tried `bind -r "\C-w"` and `bind -u unix-word-rubout` but the key is not unset and, as `bind -P | grep unix-word-rubout` reveals, there was no change in the mapping.

I played with `bind` a little and I'm able to unbind other built-in keys but not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> is bound in `stty` to `werase`. You will need to unbind it there first.

```
stty werase undef
bind '"\C-w":kill-region'
```

Answer (score 17):

By default, readline attempts to bind the control characters treated specially by the kernel's terminal driver to their readline equivalents.  (To see how your terminal is configured, run

```
stty -a
```

.)  Your terminal presumably has `Ctrl-w` set to `werase`, so bash binds it to `unix-word-rubout`.  This binding takes precedence over any keybindings that you specify in `~/.inputrc`.

To avoid this mapping, you need to set the readline variable `bind-tty-special-chars` to `off` in your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
set bind-tty-special-chars off
```